# awk, declare multiline string variable

Tags: variables, awk

Is there better ways to declare a variable that consist of multiline of string text than the following for `awk`?

```
BEGIN {
    a = "123\n\
456"
}

{
    print a;
}
```

Like in NodeJS, it has triple "`" I believe.

Comment: For what it worth, the following answer is all you want to know, for someone landed here by searching. The so called "duplicate Q/A" spent most of its effort talking about "epawk",  a certain "extended print" awk shell script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way could be define a shell variable with multiline and you could call it in `awk` program like following:

```
a='123
456

4567  abcd

test here'
```

Now define this shell variable in `awk` with name `var` and you could keep your `awk` code in much cleaner manner;by simply assigning value from shell to awk and printing it:

```
awk -v var="$a" '
BEGIN{
print var
}'
```

---

---

***OR*** if you want to only newlines as segregation then you could have it in following manner. Make use of `ORS` variable of `awk` which has default value as newline(`\n`) in it.

```
awk 'BEGIN{a="124" ORS "456";print a}'
```

Output will be as follows:

```
124
456
```

OR with using `\n` try following then:

```
awk 'BEGIN{a="124\n456";print a}'
```